# How to render a pdf in android using pdf renderer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, pdfrenderer

Hello guys how do solve this my error log I'm trying to render pdfs using the android graphics pdfrenderer class in android I've tried to observe where or how I got it wrong but I can't see yet please guys how exactly do I achieve this using this particular class any idea will be very much appreciated.

```
Shared attribute region not available to be mapped
02-04 05:35:25.750 15257 15257 W   ActivityThread                               handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@cb509ee
02-04 05:35:25.936 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       Key filePath expected String but value was a java.io.File.  The default value <null> was returned.
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.File cannot be cast to java.lang.String
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1170)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:7907)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at com.jaay.docReader.PdfActivity.onCreate(PdfActivity.java:26)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7873)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7861)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1312)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3331)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3533)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
02-04 05:35:25.950 15257 15257 W   Bundle                                       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
```

This the activity handling the pdf activity and it's display

```
public class PdfActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    String filePath = "";
    ImageView pdfView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf);
        pdfView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
        filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath");
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try{
            openPDF(file);
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        //File file = new File(filePath);
        //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        //pdfView.fromUri(uri).load();
        
        
    }
    
    
    public void openPDF(File file) throws IOException {
       // File file = new File(filePath);

        ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = null;
        fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(
            file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);

        //min. API Level 21
        PdfRenderer pdfRenderer = null;
        pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);

        final int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
        Toast.makeText(this,
                       "pageCount = " + pageCount,
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Display page 0
        PdfRenderer.Page rendererPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(0);
        int rendererPageWidth = rendererPage.getWidth();
        int rendererPageHeight = rendererPage.getHeight();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            rendererPageWidth,
            rendererPageHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        rendererPage.render(bitmap, null, null,
                            PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

        pdfView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        rendererPage.close();

        pdfRenderer.close();
        fileDescriptor.close();
    }
    
    
    
}
```

This is the code passing the pdf files using intent from fragment to activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PdfActivity.class).putExtra("filePath", file.getAbsoluteFile()));
```

Here is the pdf activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_pdf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="jaa"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pdfview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Where did I go wrong and what's odd in

```
filePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("filePath");
        File file = new File(filePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PdfActivity.class).putExtra("filePath", file.getAbsoluteFile()));

Change to:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PdfActivity.class).putExtra("filePath", file.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Answer (score 1):

there you can use this code. it's working fine for me

```
    fun getPdfThumbnail(context: Context, file:File, imageView: ImageView, pageCountTV:TextView) {
    // create a new renderer
    try {
        val pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
        val renderer = PdfRenderer(pfd)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(900, 900, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444)
        val page = renderer.openPage(0)
        val count = renderer.pageCount
        pageCountTV.text = "$count pages"
        page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)

        Glide.with(context).load(bitmap).into(imageView)
        page.close()
        renderer.close()
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys thank you for coming to my aid but I later found out the answer to my question the thing is at

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PdfActivity.class).putExtra("filePath", file.getAbsoluteFile()));
```

I was not actually returning a string but rather a file absolute path which was returned a file, this is the reason why the log said it's not possible to cast a file to string and the code kept falling back to the default string value of file path which is null my solution was to convert the file absolute path to a string by adding this
`startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), PdfActivity.class).putExtra("filePath", file.getAbsoluteFile().toString()));` 
That did the job.

Comment: I found out late after battling it but thanks though